# Can access docker container from host but that should not be possible?

Tags: docker

I have cloned this project:

https://github.com/andfanilo/vue-hello-world

and made a dockerfile for it:

```
FROM node:10
RUN apt install curl

# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
RUN mkdir /app
# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install
CMD [ "npm", "run", "serve" ]
```

I build and run it with:

```
FRONTEND_IMAGE='frontend-simple-image'
FRONTEND_CONTAINER_NAME='frontend-simple-container'

docker build -t ${FRONTEND_IMAGE} .
docker rm -f ${FRONTEND_CONTAINER_NAME}
docker run -it --name ${FRONTEND_CONTAINER_NAME} ${FRONTEND_IMAGE}
```

It builds and runs successfully:

[image]

And I can access it on my host browser:

[image]

Which is all good except I would *not* expect that I could access from my host browser according to:

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

*By default, when you create a container, it does not publish any of its ports to the outside world. To make a port available to services outside of Docker, or to Docker containers which are not connected to the container’s network, use the --publish or -p flag. This creates a firewall rule which maps a container port to a port on the Docker host. Here are some examples.*

So why does it work (accessing the web application from my host browser) without adding e.g `-p 8080:8080` to `docker run`??

Comment: Make sure that you don't have other instances or your app running without docker. Also, check your web browser caches. You can also make sure if port 8080 is owned by docker (lsof -l 8080).

Comment: Nothing else is running on my machine. If I read your comment correctly I am not supposed to be able to this right?

Comment: Yes, actually it's hard to imagine how docker could expose port of the container without any additional instructions. Imagine you will start two instances of your app. It will be not possible to distinguish between them then.

Comment: Well I just tried to start two instances and one gets 172.17.0.2:8080 while the other gets: 172.17.0.3:8080 and I can open both in my browser. So the docker documentation is not very clear/detailed on this since clearly something else is going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all working fine. To access the website you are using `172.17.0.2` which belongs to the initial Docker `bridge` network `172.17.0.0/16`. It's a basic network in which all containers are being created if you won't specify any other network.

Because `bridge` is a network created on your host machine you can freely access it using direct IP address. But if you will try to access the Vue app through `localhost:8080` or `127.0.0.1:8080` you shouldn't be able to connect, as you are using a different network. After adding `-p 8080:8080` the behavior should change and an app will be accessible through localhost.

Basically an "outside world" from Docker documentation means a network beyond the ones assigned to the container, so in your case, an "outside world" is anything but `172.17.0.0/16`.

You can read more about container communications [here](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/#communicating-to-the-outside-world).

Comment: How come this isn't well know? Is it a good idea to use the initial docker bridge network to debug?

Comment: This _only_ works on native Linux hosts, and it only works if you're on the same physical host.  `docker run -p` works on all host OSes and makes the service available to remote machines as well.  Directly using the Docker-internal IP address usually isn't right, though it does happen to work in some environments.